# increase your knowledge

Tags: knowledge, word-property

BEE, DON, EXAMINER, GLOBE, HORNET, RETRIEVER, ROO, STAR, SUN, TERRIER

These ten words can be paired up into five pairs according to a certain rule. How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Answer

> - RETRIEVER SUN
>  - TERRIER GLOBE
>  - ROOS STAR
>  - DON EXAMINER
>  - HORNET BEE

### Reasoning

> These are pairings of college sports mascots and newspaper names based on city. The cities are Baltimore (UMBC Retrievers, Baltimore Sun), Boston (BU Terriers, Boston Globe), Kansas City (UMKC Roos, The Kansas City Star), San Francisco (USF Dons, San Francisco Examiner), and Sacramento (Sac State Hornets, The Sacramento Bee).